# Github Pages only shows the title of the repository

Tags: github, dns

I use a godaddy domain for my github pages and followed the github doc. It shows like [this](https://oscarwong.info/), Here is my [repository](https://github.com/PoAhWong/poahwong.github.io). And my github pages setting is here [Github pages setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptAPp.png), and my godaddy DNS setting is here [godaddy DNS setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjAUm.png)

Please save my life big bosses!!!

Comment: Are the `A` record addresses in 1 rule or multiple rules?

Comment: I think it will look for the available one from top to bottom.